# Mono 2.4 error: ' Feature `generics' is not available in Mono mcs1 compiler. Consider using the `gmcs' compiler instead'

Tags: asp.net, mono, httphandler

Installed Mono 2.4 on Ubuntu using the instructions here:
http://www.nabble.com/forum/PrintPost.jtp?post=22841086

When I run xsp and try to run http module (http://192.168.1.6:8080/album.ashx), I get the following errors:

```
Compilation Error

Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Compiler Error Message: /tmp/fredf-temp-aspnet-0/e8a60863/194d0e44.cs(479,18) : error CS1644: Feature `generics' is not available in Mono mcs1 compiler. Consider using the `gmcs' compiler instead
/tmp/fredf-temp-aspnet-0/e8a60863/194d0e44.cs(479,50) : error CS1644: Feature `generics' is not available in Mono mcs1 compiler. Consider using the `gmcs' compiler instead
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Side-note: I didn't realise Mono 2.4 is out. Cool - I can finally get Protocol Buffers to work on it, with any luck :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be an 'xsp2' you can run that will use the 2.0 compiler instead of the 1.0 compiler.